# Bidirectional Many-to-One jpa

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I try to use bidirectional Many-to-One.

#### User.class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "executor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Task> executeTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
```

#### Task.class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE) @JoinColumn(name = "executor_id")
private User executor;
```

#### TaskBean.class

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TaskBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private TaskManager taskManager;

    @EJB
    private UserManager userManager;

    private Task task = new Task();

   public String doCreateTask() {
        task.setExecutor(currentUser);
        currentUser.getExecuteTasks().add(task);
        taskManager.createTask(task);
    }
```

#### TaskManager.class

```
 @Stateless
public class TaskManager implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public Task createTask(Task task) {
        em.persist(task);
        return task;
    }
```

I have User.class object with id. He exist on DB. I create Task.class object and insert in DB. It inserts successful with user's id. But when i select that User.class object from DB-it is selected without tasks. I hope, you can give me a solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is commonly asked.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762351/496099

Comment: Thanks. It helps me. Problem was  with cache. I turn off cache and it works  good. I will read about cache late and then i will turn on him.

Comment: I’d disagree. If you are turning off the cache and it works, it is because you are not setting the relationship. Caching can give a performance boost, so I’d advice you to fix your app now so that you could use a cache later on